# What is the appropriate way to parse a wiki dump into a format?

Tags: java, python, parsing, wiki, dump

What is the best way to parse a wiki dump into a format which contains a self generated article id and the article content and nothing else?

The article id will be a reference id and the content to be a plain text no url no references.

Comment: Is a 'wiki dump' a standard format? What's it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Database_schema

Seems very clear.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps

Seems very clear.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot

Seems to be the code you want.